# Overflow and max-height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a scrolling table with a maximum height, and to do that I have:

```
<table>
<tbody style="height: 300px; overflow:auto;">
//php for loop, populating table with <tr>s/<td>s
</tbody>
</table>
```

This works fine, but if there is only one or two rows they are stretched to fit the 300px height. I switched height to max-height but then the scroll bars never appeared, no matter how large the table got. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You could just put the table into a div and make the div scrollable?

Comment: Which browser(s), and can you demonstrate your problem? I'm [having difficulty reproducing](http://jsfiddle.net/CUXLa/) it, and had to add `display:block` to your `tbody` to even get this to work. Are you sure you are giving us all the necessary info?

Comment: @chrisdowney: That would certainly work as long as there is no `<thead>` or `<tfoot>`, that is if you want the header and footer fixed. I know OP didn't mention it.

Comment: @Wesley for this particular page there was no header or footer, so styling the div worked. I have another page that has the header row which needs to remain static, which is why I was using the tbody styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the tr's and td's are filling the height up when there are few, but you could do a couple things I think.

Try styling the cells to be a certain height, or even don't style anything to a height, and style the div that the table is in to a height. I've done the latter, and it works for me.  The cells all stay a normal height, depending on whats in them.

Comment: Styling the div rather than the table did the trick, tis always the simple things. This is why I normally just do the back end php stuff instead of the front end styling.